# IDataErrorInfo not updated

Tags: c#, wpf

I encountered a problem with the IDataErrorInfo Interface and a wizard I'm currently programming.

The intention of my programm is to ask some Inputs ( usually done with a barcode scanner) and depending on the inputs start a specific sequence. 
This is working as intendet. To make sure to catch wrong scans all inputs are check with an event ( OnValueParseFailed) If this event is triggered my current textbox is focused and all text selected:

```
    this.MyWizardViewModel.ValueParseFailed += (s, e) =>
    {
        switch (e.Parameter)
        {
            case "ProductionOrder":                            
                this.TextBoxProduction.Focus();
                this.TextBoxProduction.SelectAll();
                break;
```

The Interface itself is included this way:

```
    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if ((name == "ProductionOrder") && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ProductionOrder)))
            {
                if (this.System.FirmwareVersion == 0)
                    result = Lang.Strings.WrongEntry;
            }
```

Its working for the first run.  But if the wizard is finished or aborted and run a second time without closing the app, no error message is shown.

The Reset simply returns the app to default values.

```
    public void ResetApplikation()
    {
        this.System.Clear();  // reset System values

        this.ProductionOrder = string.Empty;
        this.BmsTypeCode = string.Empty;
        this.CellStack1TypeCode = string.Empty;
        this.CellClass1 = string.Empty;
        this.CellStack2TypeCode = string.Empty;
        this.CellClass2 = string.Empty;
        this.IsSystemProgrammed = false;
        this.IsSystemParameterized = false;

        this.MyMachine.Abort();  // reset wizard state
    }
```

While debugging I can see the Interface to be handeled correctly. But no error is displayed.

In XAML  the binding is set TwoWay

```xaml
    <TextBox Name="TextBoxProduction" Grid.Row="2" Width="200"  Margin="10"
     Style="{StaticResource TextBoxNormal}" Loaded="TextBoxProduction_Loaded"
     Text="{Binding Path=ProductionOrder, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,   
     NotifyOnValidationError=True, Delay=100,    
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I'm using MahApps but as the textbox class is based on the wpf textbox I doubt a bug in this element is the problem.  Any suggestions would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: How are you showing the wizard? Is it inside a Window? Also how are your properties defined (i.e. DependencyProperty or INotifyPropertyChanged)?

Comment: afaik WPF elements dont subscribe to IDataErrorInfo, but they do on INotifyDataErrorInfo objects.

Comment: So you should implement INotifyDataErrorInfo instead of IDataErrorInfo

Comment: @Domysee `ValidatesOnDataErrors` enables the support for `IDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: Do you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes, INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented. I haven't heard yet about INotifyDataErrorInfo. I'm currently testing this and give a feedback if this is solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of Domysee helped me.

Implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo instead of IDataErrorInfo was a major change but it fixed the problem!